# Cannot use hook to remove products from homepage

Tags: spree, overriding

I'm trying to use deface to remove the product list on the home page of a new Spree theme.

I have the following override (overrides/remove_products.rb):

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path  => "spree/layouts/spree_application",
:remove => "[data-hook='homepage_products']",
:name          => "remove_products")
```

The override doesn't appear to run.  I'm assuming that the virtual path may be incorrect?  I have other overrides working (to remove the sidebar on the homepage for example).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the file you are looking for is core/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb, so I believe your virtual path should be:

```
spree/home/index
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: Remove left Nav bar from Spree index page.

```
Step 1: create a file with name in app/overides/remove_left_nav_bar.rb

Step 2: paste following code in it.

Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/home/index',

                :name => 'remove_left_nav_bar',

                :remove => "[data-hook='homepage_sidebar_navigation']"

)

step 3: Restart your server.
```